# Autocomplete High Level Interpretation

Tags: ubuntu, graph, autocomplete, storage, trie

I've implemented a variation on the autocomplete program in python using trie-trees and matching against words from the Ubuntu standard dictionary. From my understanding trie trees are the fastest however I realize they do take up a considerable amount of space.

I'm looking to bring this to mobile however I am extremely concerned about memory limitations. My question is: what is the most efficient way to store the contents of a full-english dictionary and also ensuring optimal lookup time for entries as this structure will be queried/utilized heavily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very efficient way to store a dict is a [Directed Acyclic Word Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) (DAWG).

Here are some links:

- [Directed Acyclic Word Graph or DAWG](http://www.pathcom.com/~vadco/dawg.html) description with source code
- [Construction of the CDAWG for a Trie](http://www.i.kyushu-u.ac.jp/~takeda/papers/PSC01.pdf)
- [Implementation of directed acyclic word graph](http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/135448/Kybernetika_38-2002-1_6.pdf)

then there is a varient of Trie called [Ternary search tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search_tries), this is very memory efficinet and has fast look up speed